# B+ Trees solutions from Database Management Systems book

Tags: database, b-tree

Can someone take a look at Exercise 10.1 and the second (2) part [[manual]](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~dbbook/openAccess/thirdEdition/solutions/ans3ed-oddonly.pdf).

The questions is in page 88 and the solution in page 89 figure 10.3.

Question:

> #### 10.1
>
> > **2.** Show the B+ tree that would result from inserting a data entry with key 3 
> >         into the original tree. How many page reads and page writes does the insertion 
> >         require?

Is the resulted key correct? I believe it is not.

Original Tree
[image]

Book's Answer (After adding element 3)

> The data entry with key 3 goes on the ﬁrst leaf page F. Since F can accommodate
>       at most four data entries (d = 2), F splits. The lowest data entry of the new leaf
>       is given up to the ancestor which also splits. The result can be seen in ﬁgure 10.3.
>       The insertion will require 5 page writes, 4 page reads and allocation of 2 new
>       pages.

[image]

My Answer (After adding element 3)

> The data entry with key 3 goes on the ﬁrst leaf page F. Since F can accommodate
>       at most four data entries (d = 2), F splits and the middle data entry is moved 
>       to the parent. The lowest data entry [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu1xw.png) of the new leaf is given up to the ancestor 
>       which also splits.

[image]

**Assumption:** Is the book putting 5 as the key because if 3 was used then a place should have been wasted? We have 4 places and we would have been able to use only 3. The fourth place will have always been free.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers produce valid trees.  Why do you care whether the middle record (3) falls in the first or second data block?  The text's answer has a very slight practical advantage in that inserts of a sequence of ascending keys (which typically outnumber descending sequencees) will produce a slightly denser tree and in that case result in slightly less I/O.